# What is the auto generated __Tag Object?

Tags: custom-object, tag

I noticed after I created a custom object, an object which ends with `__Tag` has been created as well.  What does this object mean?

Answer (score 3):

These objects (tables) are automatically created when tags are enabled in an org and provide the storage mechanism for those tags.

Tags are ad-hoc labels that can be applied to records; they are a way of grouping data.

A good overview article on tags is [Salesforce Tags – The Good, The Bad, Limitations, and The Future](http://www.shellblack.com/administration/salesforce-tags-the-good-the-bad-limitations-and-the-future/). This article suggests that Chatter hashtags may eventually replace these tags.

**PS** "Eventually" has happened - see ca_peterson's comment.

Comment: By "eventually" I think you mean "in Spring14". Take a look at the release notes and you'll notice tags can't be enabled for new orgs without contacting SFDC, and chatter topics are designed to replace them.